# regex to accept currency notation and '+' sign

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex expression that excepts negative values and values with decimal points but i am not being able to make it accept ',' and '+' sign
for now it accepts 
`123` , `-123`, `-12.3`, `12.3`
but i want it to accept `12,345` and `+123`, `+123.4` also

Here is the expression

```
 var valid = (input.match(/^-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/));
        if(!valid)
         {
        control.value="";
        alert('Invalid Value')
         }
```

Comment: accept `12,345` ? . Should it also accept `1,23`?

Comment: If you wrote the original regex this would be a trivial task.

Comment: yeah it can basically I want my expression to except commas and a + sign  in it..

Comment: no i didn't that's why i asked for help

Comment: I'm not sure if *here's some code that doesn't belong to me, give me a modified version that does X* is a real question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[-+]?\d+[.,]?\d+` might just do the trick.

[demo here](http://regex101.com/r/bF4cU4/1)

PS: This will not validate proper numeric formats. i.e, `1,2` will also be matched (as per your comment, it should match).

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this,

```
^[-+]?\d+(,\d+)?(?:\.\d+)?$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sT0fL2/3)

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
var input = "+123.6"
var valid = (input.match(/^[-+]?[\d,+.]+$/));
if (!valid)
{
  alert('Invalid Value')
}
```

Comment: Your regex will match `55,` or `55+`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
var valid = (input.match(/^[-+]?\d+(?:[\.\,]\d+)?$/));
        if(!valid)
         {
        control.value="";
        alert('Invalid Value')
         }
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/next2u/h7xdvakd/)